# Upload a file or path only to SQL based on user input

Tags: php, sql, file-upload, mysqli

this is my first question on this site. I'm teaching myself code lie other women knit, I hope this is not too detailed and you can understand my question.

I'm building an equipment inventory tracking section on my concert band music library & concert planning program. I will have some band members (regular users) in our rehearsal room doing inventory on their hand held devices. To keep it easy for them I want one spot to upload documents (receipts, etc) and photos. I'm going to have a large number of photos for this project and use GD Library to do stuff with them.

```
<pre><code>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="path to my action"/>
<div style="margin-top:6px;">
<label>User Friendly Name:</label>
<input style="width:160px;" name="ed_easyname" type="text" id="easyname" maxlength="30">
</div>
<div style="margin-top:6px;">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="4000000">
<input style="width:95%;" name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile" required="required">
</div>
<div style="margin-top:8px;">
<select style="float:left;margin-top:2px; padding:1px;" name="ed_set" id="ed_set" required="required" >
<option value="0">Upload Type</option>
<option value="1">Purchase Receipt</option>
<option value="4">Miscellaneous Doc</option>
<option value="2">Repair Receipt</option> <!-- may need to move to repair table -->
<option value="11">Photo - Main</option>
<option value="12">Photo - Case</option>
<option value="13">Photo - Markings</option>
<option value="14">Photo - Damage</option>
<option value="15">Photo - Other</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="ed_enteredby" value="<?php echo $current_user->display_name; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="ed_userID" value="<?php echo $cuser_ID ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="eid" value="<?php echo $eid ?>">
<input class="smbtn-frlink" name="reset" type="reset" id="reset" value="Clear" />
<input class="smbtn-frlink" name="upload" type="submit" id="upload" value="Upload ">
```

On submit everything process and uploads to the DB like I expected. But I only want to upload docs ( $ed_set < 10 && $ed_set > 0  ) to the SQL DB, photos I want file name or path only.

QUESTION: Is this possible?

For photos (ed_set > 10) I change to name to a random name and move it to a directory with a sub directory for each piece of equipment.

My code:

```
<pre><code>
// deleted connect to db and check permissions code for this question
$eid            = check_input($_POST['eid']);
if (empty($_POST['ed_easyname'])) {
$ed_easyname    = get_uploadtype($_POST['ed_set']);
  } else {
$ed_easyname    = check_input($_POST['ed_easyname']);
  } // end process empty easy name
$ed_updateby    = check_input($_POST['ed_enteredby']);
$ed_set         = check_input($_POST['ed_set']);
$ed_userID      = check_input($_POST['ed_userID']);
function check_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
// escape text fields
    $ed_set      = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect, $ed_set);
    $ed_easyname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect, $ed_easyname);
    $ed_updateby = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect, $ed_updateby);
// get the uploaded file info
$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
if(!empty($fileName)) {
$FileExt  = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$oopsmsg  = ' files not allowed for that upload type.';
} else {
$FileExt  = 'A file was not uploaded,';
$oopsmsg  = ' you may pic from these file types for the upload type you picked.';
}
 if ( $ed_set < 10 && $ed_set > 0  ) {
    $typeerror = '
        <div style="padding:10px;">' . $FileExt . $oopsmsg . '</div>
            <div style="margin:10px;color:#900;font-weight:900;">Your file type not on this list? contact Julie. - deleted list for this question</div>
    '; // end typeerror less than 10
    $acceptedFormats = array('doc', 'docx', 'pages', 'rtf', 'pdf', 'txt', 'wpd', 'wps', 'csv', 'key', 'pps', 'ppt', 'pptx', 'tif', 'tiff', 'xlr', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'pub', 'DOC', 'DOCX', 'PAGES', 'RTF', 'PDF', 'TXT', 'WPD', 'WPS', 'CSV', 'KEY', 'PPS', 'PPT', 'PPTX', 'TIF', 'TIFF', 'XLR', 'XLS', 'XLSX', 'PUB'  );
    } // end not a photo
     else {
    $typeerror = '<div style="padding:10px;">' . $FileExt . $oopsmsg . '</div>
<div style="padding:10px;">Photos must be either JPEG, GIF, or PNG</div>';
    $acceptedFormats = array('gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'GIF', 'PNG', 'JPG', 'JPEG' );
    }   
    // I deleted a bunch of error checking for this question
        $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
        $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
        $content = addslashes($content);
        fclose($fp);

        if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
        }

        // strips blank spaces in file name
        $fileName = str_replace(" ", "", $fileName);
        // strips extra dots out of file name
        $lastDot    = strrpos($fileName, ".");
        $fileName   = str_replace(".", "", substr($fileName, 0, $lastDot)) . substr($fileName, $lastDot);

        if ( $ed_set > 10 ) { // check if photo, create dir, move to dir    
            // process a directory for each eqip ID
            $eqip_path = '../mydirectory/'.$eid;
            if ( ! is_dir($eqip_path)) {
            mkdir($eqip_path);
            }       
            // change to random name and move to folder
            $temp = explode('.', $_FILES['userfile']['name']);
            $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], '../mydirectory/'.$eid.'/' . $newfilename);     
        } // end check if photo

        // pick the file name to load in DB
        if ( $ed_set > 10 ) { 
            $processed_filename = $newfilename;         
        } else {
            $processed_filename = $fileName;
        }

$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable ( ID, set, name, type, size, content, easyname, enteredby, userID ) ".
"VALUES ('$eid', '$ed_set', '$processed_filename', '$fileType', '$fileSize', '$content', '$ed_easyname', '$ed_updateby', '$ed_userID')";
// deleted closing code
?>
```

Thank you,
Julie

Comment: It looks like you know the new filename. What's the problem to add it to the DB?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what I see in the SQL DB, it appears to be also storing it there. Won't a ton of photos slow my DB?

Comment: & Thank you for the quick response :)

Comment: But you are not storing the photos, but only filenames. And... what is the question anyway?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I'm overthinking it. I don't want the photos slowing down my DB. 

So, storing a file to the database vs. only storing a file name and putting the file in a directory are basically the same thing as far as the MySQL DB is concerned? The how depends on what I want to do with it?

If so, question answered.

Comment: No. it's not the same. Files should be never stored in database. So, while storing only filenames you are doing it the right way.